# Hair partially disappearing in render after combing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hair

I got a weird problem. Patches of hair on a rug for a bathroom scene are disappering in my render, but only if I entered particle edit Mode and combed the hair before.

So, I start out setting up my hair system, when I hit render without entering the particle edit Mode I get a nice render just like its supposed to look. All the hair is also howing in the viewport before and after this render.

I enter particle edit mode, just make a single tiny stroke with the comb, exit into object mode again. All the hair is still showing in the viewport at this point, I can also so see my "comb-job" in the viewport.

When I now hit render though, whole patches of hair just disappear from the render. Its also not like that the areas I combed before disappear and the ones I left untouched are still showing, there seems to be no connection between where I comb and what disappears.

After this render finishes the hair (same hair as in render result) is also missing in the viewport.

My emitter is just a plane, rotation and scale all applied, with a subsurf modifier. Use modifier stack is enabled.
I´m aware that particles won´t render when you´re still in particle edit mode, I always changed back to object mode before rendering.
Does anyone have an idea whats causing this and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of your particle settings?

Comment: Sure, added it to my first post.

Comment: Nobody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have $300000$ individual hairs right now. I suspect that your issue stems from that very high number of edited particles. To fix this, use **Particle Children**. Set your Emission number to something lower, like $3000$ or $1000$. Then, enable *Interpolated* children:

[image]

You can set the *Render* parameter so that the total number of children is equal to $300000$, (i.e. $3000\cdot 100=300000$).

You can now use **Particle Edit** to comb your particles. They should take up less memory now, and hopefully render correctly.

Comment: I´ll try what you suggestet tomorrow.

But i dont think this is the culprit, besides the rug I have another 5 towels in my scene, each with with a million hairs. All 4 render without any problems. I even deactivated them for the test renders in the screenshots your seeing to to make sure "too many particles" couldnt be the case.

Comment: did you ever fix this.  This is happening to me too now.  Renders fine until I use particle edit mode.  Just a few hundred leaves in my case.

Comment: This behavior is most likely a bug, and isn't intended. What I've answered is a suggested best practice to get around it, but it would perhaps be a good idea to [report a bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1378/26640).

Comment: Thanks scott, seems really odd because I have other objects in the scene that are using particle edit and they appear to work perfectly, so it can't be a render setting thats wrong etc.  Stumped.  Thanks anyway.